# What server URL should be used for the `oc login` command when using OpenShift's PaaS?

Tags: openshift

What do I provide for the server URL in the `oc login` tool, when using the OpenShift PaaS?

I'm trying to migrate my OpenShift Online v2 app to v3, following [the instructions for PHP apps linked to from OpenShift's Migration Center](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/migrating_applications/web_framework_applications.html#dev-guide-migrating-web-framework-applications-php). That page says to run something following the pattern `oc new-app https://github.com/<github-id>/<repo-name>.git --name=<app-name> -e <ENV_VAR_NAME>=<env_var_value>`. After tracking down a download for oc (which wasn't easy), I tried running that command with my repo URL*; this results in:

```
$ oc new-app https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git --name=PROJECTNAME
error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please login or point to an existing, complete config file:

  1. Via the command-line flag --config
  2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
  3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config

To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.
```

Not knowing what subcommand of `oc config` to use, I searched and found [Get Started with the CLI](https://docs.openshift.com/online/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html), which says to use `oc login` to start the configuration process. But when I run that, I get:

```
Server [https://localhost:8443]:
```

What do I provide for the URL here, when using the OpenShift PaaS (i.e. not a local installation)? I've tried things like `https://openshift.com/` and the URL of my web app, but both of them result in

```
error: The server was unable to respond - verify you have provided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running.
```

* I decided to use Bitbucket instead of GitHub; I'm not sure if this is unsupported, or (if it's supported) whether I should be providing `USERNAME@bitbucket.org`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is right over there in the web console.
Click on `(?)` help icon right beside your user name on top right corner. Select `'Command Line Tool'` from the drop down menu.

Alternatively, it is there in the URL :

```
http://<openshift url>/console/command-line
```

e.g. it is mentioned on the below URL for me:

```
https://console.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com/console/command-line
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah. There was a PEBCAK, in which I hadn't yet even created a v3 plan for myself yet, so all I was seeing was the old v2 UI, which didn't have that.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing for 10 minutes and the only answer I found was here; no where on openshift's docs.

Answer (score 6):

In the RedHat OpenShift Online web console, click on the `(?)` help icon right beside your user name in the top right corner. Select `'Command Line Tools'` from the drop down menu.

A pop-up window appears with a section "oc - OpenShift Command Line Interface (CLI)", and there's a link for `Copy Login Command`. Click that and it takes you to a page like

> https://oauth-openshift.apps.ca-central-1.starter.openshift-online.com/oauth/token/display?code=Ge.....

(You may be prompted at this point to log into the Redhat Portal, do that if necessary.)

The page will then show the text

> Display Token

Click `Display Token`

It will show output similar to this:

> Log in with this token
>
> oc login --token=... --server=https://api.ca-central-1.starter.openshift-online.com:6443

Answer (score 6):

On the web console, click in your profile and then you can see "copy Login command" like this:
[image]

Then you just click on it and do it again on the button "Display token" in the new browser tab. Here is what your token looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just tried actually signing up for an OpenShift v3 Starter plan (which I hadn't done before because I didn't want to get ahead of myself, and the migration guide hadn't said to do so yet). That course of action did give me access to [the "Command Line Tools" menu item under the `?` menu](https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/console/command-line), which gives the command line as `oc login https://api.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com --token=<hidden>`. (The hidden token is copied to the clipboard if you click the clipboard icon to the right of that line.)

Comment: There is also an online interactive tutorial which walks you through how to access an OpenShift 3 cluster at https://learn.openshift.com/

Answer (score 1):

I created an account for OpenShift v3 Starter plan.
Then I installed OC Tool available [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.5.1/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit.tar.gz).
I created a project called spike1 on US west.
Finally when running *oc login* and set Server URL to https://console.starter-us-west-1.openshift.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a project in public OpenShift. It redirect to my console 
starter-us-west-1.openshift.com/console/
If you wana login to openshift using CLI. 
command is 
`oc login https://console.starter-us-west-1.openshift.com`